# Angular 7 add Javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, angular

My intention is to add a javascript plugin, namely this one:

> https://steven.codes/typerjs/

So far, my approach was to add its JS file in my assets folder and added the path to `angular.json`.

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/typer.js"
            ]
```

My next step was to declare a `var` in the component and to try to call it in `ngOnInit()`.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as AOS from 'aos';

declare var Typer: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-background',
  templateUrl: './background.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./background.component.scss']
})
export class BackgroundComponent implements OnInit {

  rotate = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rotate = !this.rotate;
    AOS.init();
    Typer.init();
  }

}
```

**I don't get any errors, but it's not working. Does somebody know a working approach?**

Comment: Adding it to the `scripts` array in `angular.json` will make sure it is loaded with your app and most probably in the window scope. But, I couldn't find any `init()` method in the typer documentation. AFAIK it only relies on the classnames `typer` and `cursor`.

Comment: and also, as far as I understand, the typer library should export members to have a possibility to use it in this style of importing

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options that may help.
First - Node style **require**:

```js
var typer = require("typer");
```

Second one use it like you already did with **aos**:

```js
import * as typer from 'typer';
```

In this case you must be sure that your `.js` lib can be found. You have added it to `angular.js` so that should works.

In both cases the initialization should be the same:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.rotate = !this.rotate;
    AOS.init();
    typer.init();
  }
```